# Как присвоить имя функци jQuery для вызова её из функции javascript

Tags: jquery, javascript, события

Есть кнопка. На неё подвешен обработчик события onclick  в JavaScript (проверка правильности заполнения формы).

```
function checkForm (){
     if...
     else...
}
```

Если всё хорошо заполнено, надо плавно передвинуть экран на определённую позицию (поскролить). Для этого используется jQuery.

```
$('#showShip').click(function () {  
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('a[name="ship"]').offset().top-150}, 800);        })
```

Как сделать так, чтобы вторая функция выполнялось только в случае успеха выполнения первой(форма заполнена правильно). Пробовал так

```
var goToShip = function (){$('html, body').animate...}
$('#showShip').click(goToShip())
```

И так:

```
function goToShip (){$('html, body').animate...}
```

и вставлял goToShip () в конец JavaScript. Страница скролится при загрузке или по клику без проверки формы.

Comment: function checkForm (){
        if (<ваше условие>){
            goToShip();
        } else...
    }

Или я что-то не понял?

Comment: Если я прописываю ф-цию
function goToShip (){$('html, body').animate...}
то страница скролится сразу, по загрузке. Если так
$(document).ready(function (){
 $('#showShip').click(function goToShip () {
  $('html, body').animate({...})});
, то при вызове из функции JavaScript, пишет goToShip undefined

Comment: Вот сайт: http://mytrips.my1.ru/Voyage.htm

Comment: Что то у вас как то странно все, за сайт спасибо, окунул в 90-е :)) Щас что нибудь накатаю, через минут пять

Comment: Я кстати правильно понимаю, что вы хотите чтобы люди вводили дату, нажимали поехали и страница скролилась до участка соответствующего введенной дате ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#btn').on('click', function(e) {
        // любой селектор, абсолютный, относительный
        var $formElem = $(e.target).parents('form');
        if(isValidForm($formElem)) {
            // вызов функции анимации
        } else {
            // вызов функции показа ошибки
        }
    });

function isValidForm(formElem)
{
    //somecode, return bool;
}
```

Comment: Сейчас попробую.
Сомнительный комплимент, конечно, но всё равно спасибо. Это мой первый сайт.

Comment: Да, спасибо, всё работает!
Но, хотелось бы всё же выяснить то, что у меня в заголовке вопроса стоит: Как присвоить имя функци jQuery для вызова её из функции javascript.
Предположим, это jQuery анимирование я вынес в отдельную функцию:

$.fn.scrollSmooth = function() {  
    return $('html, body').animate({... };

Как теперь вызвать её из функции JavaScript?

function checkForm (){
if ...
scrollSmooth()
}  

Так не работает, пишет scrollSmooth - undefined.

Comment: То, что вы написали, лишено здравого смысла. $.fn.SomeFuncName = function() {}. Это расширение объекта jQuery. То есть вы таким образом пишете метод для объекта jQuery, и соответственно использовать вы будете это так $().someFuncName().  В вашем случае это $().scrollSmooth()

Comment: Но реализация вашей функции такова, что она не должна быть методом объекта jQuery. Это самая что ни на есть обычная функция. Если вы решили сделать ее расширением jQuery из за проблем с видимостью, то вам следует знать, что var myFunc = function() {} надо объявлять до использования, а function myFunc() {} можно написать в любом месте, главное на одном уровне видимости.

Comment: Спасибо ещё раз. Я вроде пробовал и так ( var myFunc = function() {}) и так ( function myFunc() {}), объявлял до использования, и всё равно undefind. 
А проблемы видимости, это когда я не могу вызвать функцию/метод jQuery, изнутри функции JavaScript?